# How to call a method from cell renderer in ag grid -created a drop down click event not firing from option?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

this is my aggrid columndef

```
{
  headerName: 'Type Of Pin',
  field: 'pinType',
  width: 160,
  cellRenderer: this.typeOfPin,
  suppressSorting: true
}

typeOfPin(params) {
    console.log(params);
    // const eDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // const disableVal = true;
    // eDiv.innerHTML =
    return  '<div><select placeholder="Select" class="form-control ag-form-control">' +
      '<option></option>' +
      '<option (click)="test()" selected>Number</option>' +
      '<option onClick="test()" >Random</option>' +
      '</select></div>';
}
```

```ts
test(){
    click('hi');
}
```

normal select option is forming using cellrenderer in aggrid dynamically the click event is not able to bind during creation and suggestion how to resolve the issue i want a click event please help...tried valueformatter and everything but method i am not able to call....

Answer (score 5):

Got the solution for this. First in cell renderer put the `bind(this)`, and then do the same as below. You can pass the value of your drop down.

Hope this helps.

```
{
    headerName: 'Type Of Pin',
    field: 'pinType',
    width: 160,
    cellRenderer: this.typeOfPin.bind(this),
    suppressSorting: true
}
```

```
typeOfPin(params) {
    console.log(params);
    const eDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-this-assignment
    const self = this;
    eDiv.innerHTML =
        '<select placeholder="Select" class="form-control ag-form-control">' +
        '<option></option>' +
        '<option value="number">Number</option>' +
        '<option value="random">Random</option>' +
        '</select>';
    eDiv.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log('button clicked');
        self.test(event.target.value);
    });

    return eDiv;
}
```